# FullCalendar - How to add extra information to each day

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm wondering if it is possible to add extra information to days, perhaps at the left sup corner, opposite to the day number.

The main idea here is to add some html, such as a link that shows a popover or dialog when we click it.

I have attached some screenshots that describe it a little bit better.

Well, I noticed I'm unable to attach files due to my insufficient reputation.

I hope the text can explain by itself what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You can put some working example links for a proper idea

Answer (score 0):

There is a callback called [`dayRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/) that will allow you to modify the html of each day cell.

```
function( date, cell ) {
    $(cell).html("some html");
}
```